# How am I able to output an integer and float depending on the input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python 3.  I am trying to be able to print an output as either an integer or a float depending on which type is used.  How am I able to format the code so that if they enter 3 as the radius it outputs "3" and if they were to input 3.5 it would output the radius as "3.5"?  Are there any suggestions?

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a circle? ")
again=input("Enter 'y' for yes, or enter 'n' to exit the program: ")

while (again=='y'):
    pi = 3.14
    radius = raw_input(" Input the radius of the circle: ")

    area = pi * radius * radius
    print("A circle with a radius of " + str(float(radius)) + " has an area of " +  "{0:.2f}".format(area))
    print()
    print("Would you like to run another? ")
    again = input("Enter 'y' to run another, enter 'n' to exit: ")

print("Have a nice day :) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

for debuging or just to know the type of value you can use

```
print(type(some_var))
```

if are you want to use it in if statement use with isinstance function

```
if isinstance(radius, int):
   print("int")
if isinstance(radius, float):
    print("float")
```

more info here
[Differences between isinstance() and type() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

First, a few things:

The difference between "input" and "raw_input" is that input will return a number value whereas raw_input will return a string value. Anything you get with raw_input will have to be cast to an int or a float if you intend to use it in a numerical operation. likewise, you have to use raw_input if you expect the user to enter a word or phrase.

Second, the print funtion places the output on a new line automatically. if you want to add another new line to your output, use '\n' in your string.

Finally, casting radius to a float ensured it would print out as a float. if you don't cast it to a float before casting it to a string, python will do the formatting for you.

Below I took your code, commented out the flawed parts, and placed my fixes directly below them:

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a circle? ")

# again = input("Enter 'y' for yes, or enter 'n' to exit the program: ")
again = raw_input("Enter 'y' for yes, or enter 'n' to exit the program: ")

while (again == 'y'):

    pi = 3.14

    # radius = raw_input(" Input the radius of the circle: ")
    radius = input("Input the radius of the circle: ")

    area = pi * radius * radius

    # print("A circle with a radius of " + str(float(radius)) + " has an area of " +  "{0:.2f}".format(area))
    print("A circle with a radius of " + str(radius) + " has an area of " +  "{0:.2f}".format(area))

    # print()
    # print("Would you like to run another? ")

    print("Would you like to run another? ")

    # again = input("Enter 'y' to run another, enter 'n' to exit: ")
    again = raw_input("Enter 'y' to run another, enter 'n' to exit: ")

print("Have a nice day :) ")
```

Hope this helps!

Use this instead for python 3:

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a circle?")
again = input("Enter 'y' for yes, or enter 'n' to exit the program: ")

while (again == 'y'):

    pi = 3.14

    radius = input("Input the radius of the circle: ")
    area = pi * (float(radius) ** 2)

    print("A circle with a radius of " + str(radius) + " has an area of " + "{0:.2f}".format(area))

    print("Would you like to run another?")
    again = input("Enter 'y' to run another, enter 'n' to exit: ")

print("Have a nice day :)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was looking everywhere and I was unable to figure it out, I will adjust my code accordingly. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Comment: When i tried using your code I got this as an error                                         >>> circleArea()
Do you want to find the area of a circle? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    circleArea()
  File "/Users/shor269/Desktop/Python-Horn/Geometry.py", line 49, in circleArea
    again = raw_input("Enter 'y' for yes, or enter 'n' to exit the program: ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: My bad. The advice I gave for input and raw_input only applies to python 2. In python 3 "input" returns a string, which you then have to cast.

Also, in python you can make exponents by using **.

For example:

    print(10 ** 2)

would print out 100.

I'll add a fixed version of the code to the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: It worked out for me when I ran it! Also, it is fine I was in no rush, I was really stuck on this and you helped me out so thanks again!